# Can't add the ruby on rails Quandl gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm Clement a ruby on rails beginner. I'm working on an app which requires a stock and financial feeds. Fortunately, I got a free working financial and stock charts gem in the ruby on rails gem store, called [quandl-ruby](https://github.com/quandl/quandl-ruby). But I'm having a little problem in procedures for getting the gem worked on my app. I will be much grateful if anyone can walk me through this.

Comment: What is the little problem you are having ?

Comment: Dont know how tog g about it. Just want someone to help me through that.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: `gem 'quandl'` add this to your `Gemfile`

Step 2: run `bundle install`

Step 3: create a file `config/initializers/quandl.rb` and add the following to it:

```
require 'quandl'
Quandl::ApiConfig.api_key = 'tEsTkEy123456789' #Replace this with your access key
Quandl::ApiConfig.api_version = '2015-04-09' #version you wish to access the api with
```

Step 4: Open `rails console` and try the following:

```
require 'quandl'
Quandl::Dataset.get('WIKI/AAPL')
```

Try out other options as well from https://github.com/quandl/quandl-ruby and then implement your functionality using this gem.

Comment: Is itt advisable to create a specific controller for that since its a json api

Comment: @ClementNice Yes, you can!

Comment: @ClementNice did you try the above steps ?

Comment: Yes and dont know where to go after that steps

Comment: You must have got response in your `rails console` , that is how exactly you need to implement your logic in your app .